# Какие пунктуационные знаки нужны?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, пунктуация

Какие пунктуационные знаки нужны в этом предложении?

> Единственное что напоминало здесь в
> этом ледяном ущелье о реальной жизни
> это птицы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное, что напоминало здесь, в этом ледяном ущелье, о реальной жизни, - это птицы.

Comment: а почему перед тире запятая нужна?

Comment: "что напоминало здесь, в этом ледяном ущелье, о реальной жизни" - придаточное предложение, которое нужно "закрыть" запятой

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!